# Java: WeakReference.get() returns differently after System.gc()

Tags: java, get, null, garbage-collection, weak-references

I tried to see when weak reference returns `null` by `get()`:

```
String string = new String("abc");
WeakReference<String> wi = new WeakReference<>(string);
WeakReference<String> sr = new WeakReference<>(new String("another"));
System.out.println(wi.get());
System.out.println(sr.get());
System.gc();
System.out.println("After gc() wi = " + wi.get());
System.out.println("After gc() sr =: " + sr.get());
```

It prints:

```
abc
another
After gc() wi = abc
After gc() sr =: null
```

Why after `gc()`, wi still holds reference, and sr is holding `null`? I changed `String` type into `Integer` or my own class, same result.

What makes the core difference here?

Comment: `String string = new String("abc");` - reference to string is still on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A weak reference is a reference that does not protect the referenced object from collection by a garbage collector, unlike a strong reference.

Because `abc` is held by the strong reference `string`, the object will not be eligible to GC it as there is an existing living reference to it and thus the weak reference still refers to it. In the second case, the only reference to `another` is `sr` a weak reference and GC is then free to make what it refers to as eligible to deletion.

Deletion may be "virtual", that depends on the Garbage Collector used.

Comment: There term “delete” is misleading, nothing gets deleted at all. The weak reference will be *cleared* if the garbage collector detects that the object became unreachable, with an emphasis on the detection. Run the program with `-Xcomp` and you will get a different result. You will get yet another result when using either, `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC` or `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`.

Comment: @Holger perfectly true, but OP is a beginner... I may change to eligible to GC.